# how to hide a part of a page based on user role

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am so confused about authorization in Laravel between gats, policies, making roles table, etc.

I am working on a medical system that has Admins, doctors, patients, assistants, and lab workers.

so, how to make an Authorization like show and hide part of pages, menu, edit and delete patients depending on the user type

**note: I don't want to use any library for that, I just want to understand the Laravel concept**

Comment: are you trying to make a customized role or permanent role like admin, basic user, moderator?

Comment: You can conditionally show/hide parts of a blade view based on what the user can and can't do. [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-blade-templates). Note that you need to differentiate between `admin, doctor` etc and authorisation. You need to define a policy that determines what each kind of user can do

Comment: You can simply add conditions in your blade file. `@if($user->isRole()) can see this content @endif` and ofc the function `isRole()` checks if the user is certain role inside your user model.

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera it is going to be permanent role

Comment: If you’re just wanting to get a better understanding of authorisation in Laravel, then the docs are a great place to start. The Laracasts Laravel 8 from Scratch series also [has a section on authorization](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/62) if you’re more of a visual learner.